# TypeScript type restrictions sometimes not applied

Tags: typescript

I'm designing an authentication backend with TypeScript. I have the following types to describe a user or a guest:

```
export type LoadingUser = {
  loading: true;
};

export type AuthenticatedUser = {
  loading: false;
  error: string | null;
  loggedIn: true;
  name: string;
};

export type GuestUser = {
  loading: false;
  error: string | null;
  loggedIn: false;
};
```

`LoadingUser` is used to indicate when the user is still being fetched, the frontend could show a spinner here. Notice it's **either** only `loading: true` with no other properties, or `loading: false` with other properties, and then either `loading: false; loggedIn: false; error: string | null` with no other properties, or `loading: false; loggedIn: true; error: string | null` with other properties.

I'm then using these types to define my `User` type:

```
export type User =
  | LoadingUser
  | AuthenticatedUser
  | GuestUser;
```

I want to use this to type-check all my API responses, but I have come across the following problem

```
const user: User = {
  loading: true,
  loggedIn: true, // Problem: this property is allowed on this object even though `loading: true`
};
```

When I'm just using `AuthenticatedUser` and `LoadingUser` together, or `GuestUser` with `LoadingUser`, this problem does not happen. **TypeScript then correctly errors and tells me `loggedIn` does not exist on type `LoadingUser`** like I want.

Why does using type `User` make TypeScript not report this error?

*In advance: Thank you so much for helping me, I've been struggling with this for days!*

Answer (score 2):

```
export type LoadingUser = {
    loading: true;
    loggedIn?: never;
};
```

The problem is that assigning `{ loading: true, loggedIn: true }` to `LoadingUser` is correct (and actually should not be an error) by the types theory - the object conforms to the `LoadingUser` type constraint. Typescript's restriction *Object literal may only specify known properties* is an extra helper because in practice specifying unknown properties in object literal is usually a mistake (or bad type design) althrough it is theoretically OK, but this helper can definitely not catch all possible cases.

However by declaring `loggedIn?: never` you explicitly disallow `LoadingUser` to have this attribute, then your "bad" object will not conform to this interface and report and error.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I was taught that the difference between types and interfaces is that interfaces allow extra properties while types do not. Apparently this is not the case?  Is there any way in TypeScript to allow only these exact specified properties and not any other?

Comment: Types and interfaces have more differences, e.g. type can contain unions (type A = B | C) while interface can not. Or some tricky ones, like this I stumbled upon yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62265261/1660584 and still don't know what's going on :)

According to restricting properties - no, at least no simple direct way. Maybe some nasty hack, but in traditional object typing it does not make sense. Any object can contain any unknown property since you should work only with known properties and receive any object suitable by Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: You're right, I need to change my mindset about extra properties! Thanks so much for helping out